# Laravel Accessor for ID column

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have a table with column **ID**. I want to make a accessor for the same column.

Model.

```
protected $table = 'repair_category';
protected $fillable = ['ID,','Name','Active','Background_Color','Icon_File_Name','ListOrder'];
protected $primaryKey = 'ID';
```

I tried

```
public function getIDAttribute($value)
{
    return Crypt::encrypt($value);
}
```

and

```
public function getIdAttribute($value)
{
    return Crypt::encrypt($value);
}
```

But its not working.

Anyone please suggest a way to solve this issue.

Comment: so what is your primary key and how do you define it in your model?

Comment: I think there is a design problem with your database : your primary key should only be an integer, and be unique. A crypted content can generate a collision (Two different elements generating the same hash), so this is not an unique element.

Why can't you make another column for the crypted content ?

And, also : why do you need to crypt your IDs ?

Comment: @MarcBrillault, I want to hide the PK of the table row entirely from browser. so that I want to crypt the ID from the table.  I can get the result when I change the PK column to id, but I dont wish to change the column name.

Comment: So, why don't you generate a crypted content in another column, and use this column in your routes and controller methods, instead of the primary key ?

Comment: See, I can get the solution through process the array before returning to view and make the ID as encrypted. But Laravel Accessor method will be more prefer for me due to code quality. So that I request you to any possible way for my idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading from $this->attributes[] in the accessor method

```
protected $primaryKey = 'ID';

public function getIDAttribute()
{
    return Crypt::encrypt($this->attributes['ID']);
}
```

Comment: Not working with your answer, its return without encrypting.

Comment: Kind of weird, as it nicely works for me - could you add a piece of code that makes you think it's not working? And BTW. I've just spotted a typo in your 'fillable'. Actually there should be no "ID" if it's autoincrement, but also it's there with a trailing coma.